# Identify form the method is being called from

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, methods, parameter-passing

I have a global method (in a module) that multiple forms are calling. I can't figure out how to pass/identify the calling form so that it's controls are recognised when referenced in the method:

```
Public Sub SomeFunction(callingForm As Form)
    callingForm.ErrorProvider.SetError(TextBox1, "Faux pas!")
End Sub

Public Sub SomeOtherFunction(callingForm As Form)
    SomeFunction(Me)
End Sub
```

I the above example, I've attempted passing the form as a parameter but I'm being told:

> ErrorProvider is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.Form.

Comment: the calling `Type` is actually `Form1` or similar - `Form` is the generic base class all other forms inherit from.  You should not  export things like that to generic global handlers for just that reason - leave data validation in the form(s).  You end up adding a bunch of code to break things back out anyway

Comment: @Plutonix I have global method in a module that validates all text boxes in the exact same manner across several forms. Doesn't it make more sense to consolidate it?

Comment: what exactly does it validate?  the only thing I can think of that would be common among all TBs on All forms is something like cant be 0 length.  Name, address, zip, state, phone, email, IP address, favorite color would all have different rules as to content for real DV.

Comment: `someTextBox As Object` checks for empty/null. `checkExactLength As Boolean` when `True`, checks if MaxLength is reached when specific character amount is required, `checkFormat As String` will run additional checks for formats like email, age, promotional code etc.

Comment: Why you need to pass a form parameter if validation function do same things for all?

Comment: @Fabio If I don't specify the form by prefixing ErrorProvider with the form name, I'm being told ErrorProvider is not declared. I need to method to know what ErrorProvider on what form I'm referring to.

Comment: but see, that is the problem - you are having to tell some Other Thing what the rules are when the form could enforce and apply them directly.  In a bus app that is the tip of the iceberg - there are all sorts of conditional things  `If Age < x Then ...`  Debugging those is a bloody nightmare

Comment: if you are intent on doing that, pass the EP explicitly, or pass the form name and let the generic thing get the form reference from  `OpenForms`

Comment: @Plutonix By explicit, do you mean something like `someErrorProvider As ErrorProvider`?

Comment: Or make a Validate function return `Boolean` value. Then in the form `If Validate(...) = false Then Me.ErrorProvider.SetError(...)`

Comment: @Fabio Unfortunately, one of the key purposes of my method is to avoid having to set the errors outside of the method, to reduce duplicitous code.

Comment: You can create a base form with validate function, and make other forms be derived from that

Comment: Are you trying to call a function from different form or an object from diff form? if an object from diff form u should do like this _italic_**bold** 'formname.objectname.event = true/false/""..etc' example if you want to pass a text value from form 1 to form 2.. you will have to use _italic_**bold**'form2.textbox1.text = "pass value"'

Comment: @GirlsdoCode I'm passing a text box as an `Object` parameter and attempting passing the form that's making the call either as an `Object` or `Form` parameter. I'm calling a function, situated in `MyGlobalFunctions.vb`, from several different forms.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty common, to want to treat all your forms the same, yet different. You will want to create another class that each form can implement. This allows you to do something specific... generically.

Create a class similar to this, call it and the function whatever you want:

```
Public Interface IErrorForm
    Sub MyValidate
End Interface
```

Implement it in your forms:

```
Public Class Form1
    Implements IErrorForm

Public Sub MyValidate() Implements IErrorForm.MyValidate
    '...Your code here
    'TextBox1.Text = "Faux pas!"
End Sub
```

Now, wherever you want to call the function, you could do something like this:

```
Public Sub SomeFunction(callingForm As Form)
    If GetType(IErrorForm).IsAssignableFrom(xFrm.GetType) Then
        CType(xFrm, IErrorForm).MyValidate()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I've created a new class file, `Class1.vb` (first code block). Where exactly do I implement the class (second code block)? I've tried at the beginning and end of `Public Class SomeForm` but the code editor is not accepting it. Also, is `From1` (second code block) meant to read `Form1`?

Comment: This approach mean he will need to rewrite `MyValidate` function for every form

Comment: The second block is in your form, in my example, it is form1. Just under your class declaration, put the implements code, then hit enter and the other code (`Public Sub MyValidate() Implements IErrorForm.MyValidate`) will be auto-generated,

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with returning value from `Validate` function
As you mentioned in the comments

> ...one of the key purposes of my method is to avoid having to set the
>   errors outside of the method, to reduce duplicitous code

As I understand you want `Validate` function check, given control as parameter, for errors and show error message through `ErrorProvider`.
My suggestion will be shared `Validate` function return string value, which contains error message generated after validating control
If no error then function return `Nothing` or `String.Empty`

```
Public Function Validate(ctrl As Object, formats As String) As String
    Dim errorMessage As String = Nothing 'or String.Empty
    ' Your validating code here
    ' If no error errorMessage = Nothing
    Return errorMessage         
End Function
```

Then in the form (possible in the `Validated` event handler)

```
'....
Me.MyErrorprovider.SetError(Me.MyTextBox, 
                            MyGlobalFunctions.Validate(Me.MyTextBox, "formats"))
```